# How to get private key from bitcoin wallet?

Tags: transactions

My wallet just won't synchronize and I have 10 bitcoins there. I need to use blockchain but I cannot get my import key. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Blockchain.info can create a new wallet from an existing Bitcoin.org client's wallet.dat with a simple Drag and Drop:

- https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet

The wallet.dat is in the [data directory](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory).

Answer (score 0):

Start your bitcoind/bitcoin-qt with `-rescan` switch.
Then it should synchronize after re-scanning the chain.
Otherwise you can use RPC command `dumpprivkey <bitcoinaddress>` to export private key. Such an exported key you can import to another wallet with `importprivkey <bitcoinprivkey> [label] [rescan=true]`. You can also import it to your MtGox wallet.